# How do I clear a RatingControl and make it 0 stars in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

My UI:

[image]

Here is my XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4">
    <RatingControl x:Name="mainRating" Margin="5, 10, 10, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.Name="Simple RatingControl" IsClearEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="False" ValueChanged="MainRating_ValueChanged" />
    <Button x:Name="clearRatingButton" Content="Clear Rating" Click="ClearRatingButton_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</StackPanel>
```

And here is my code for when the "Clear Rating" button is clicked:

```
private void ClearRatingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainRating.Value = 0.0;
    clearRatingButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void MainRating_ValueChanged(RatingControl sender, object args)
{
    clearRatingButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But whenever that code is called, the stars on the control in the UI is always set to 1 star, not 0. Why?

[image]

Comment: Did you tried `mainRating.Value = -1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview) have associated metadata with it. The public instance's property get/set methods are merely [wrappers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview#dependency-properties-and-windows-runtime-properties) over dependency properties `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods.

And you can also [reset the value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview#default-value-and-clearvalue) to it's default value using the [ClearValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.clearvalue) method.

In the case of [RatingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.ratingcontrol.valueproperty), that would be a code like this:

```
mainRating.ClearValue(RatingControl.ValueProperty);
```

Note this can be seen as a shortcut to:

```
var dp = RatingControl.ValueProperty;
var def = dp.GetMetadata(typeof(RatingControl)).DefaultValue; // -1d
mainRating.SetValue(dp, def);
```

Comment: `mainRating.ClearValue` worked, thanks!